# Using UNIX sockets with Dart

Tags: dart, unix-socket

Currently I can use a TCP socket :

```dart
final socket = await Socket.connect('127.0.0.1', 8888);
```

I would like to use a [UNIX socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket).
Is there a way to do this with Dart ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

UNIX sockets are supported in Dart 2.7.2 (see [this pr](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/commit/ed83a28d3ee46437dcd624300ec6c003093a6659) or [this issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/21403)).

You need to use `InternetAddress` constructor with the optional parameter `type` set as `unix`:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

...
// With String address
final host = InternetAddress(address, type: InternetAddressType.unix);
// OR with UInt8List raw address
final host = InternetAddress.fromRawAddress(rawAddress, type: InternetAddressType.unix);
final socket = await Socket.connect(host, port);
```